# Rails wrap two process to the db transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've never done that before and I don't know if it is possible. I've got two process which I thing should most likely be wrapped in a database transaction to have the guarantee that either all changes in the database from the transaction will be made or no changes will be made.

```
process.campaign_code.update(state: 'used')
Campaign.find(process.campaign_code.campaign_id).increment!(:used_campaign_codes_amount, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  process.campaign_code.update!(state: 'used')
  Campaign.find(process.campaign_code.campaign_id).increment!(:used_campaign_codes_amount, 1)
end
```

If any of the commands in the transaction throw an error, all SQL transactions in the block will be reverted.

EDIT: It's also worth changing `update` to `update!` to ensure an error is thrown if the update is unsuccessful, otherwise it can fail without throwing an error and the block will continue.

Comment: Thanks for that, should I define new method and call it in the code or leave like it is and it will be processed automatically ?

Comment: No worries, I think common practice is to leave the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do` block as most developers recognise it and know what the intentions are

Comment: Since `ActiveRecord::Base` methods are inherited you could replace it with `ApplicationRecord` or any of your other models.